# Is this partition of $X$ in measurable space $(X, S)$ countable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

As part of a proof on [this website](http://www.yaronhadad.com/why-arent-there-infinitely-countable-sigma-algebras/), we have that $S$ is an infinite countable $\sigma$-algebra defined on a set $X$. Also, we have a function $f:X\rightarrow S$ defined as $f(x) := \bigcap_{x\in A \in S} A$.

I get that $f(x) \cap f(y) = \emptyset$ for every $x \neq y$.

However, I do not fully understand the claim "$f(X)$ provides us with a partition of $X$". Does this mean that the set $\{f(x)\}_{x \in X}$ is the partition, thus $f(X) = \{f(x)\}_{x \in X}$?

Eventually I would like to find out whether the partition is countable. Using the definition of the partition as $f(X) = \{f(x)\}_{x \in X}$, it seems to me that the partition is countable when $X$ is countable. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume they mean $f(X) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in X \}$, as you suggest. (It's horrible notation, though...) Since $x \in f(x)$ for each $x \in X$, and $f(x) \cap f(y) = \varnothing$ for all $x \ne y$, it follows that $f(X)$ is a partition of $X$.

Moreover, since the partition is indexed by the elements of $X$, it is in fact in *bijection* with the elements of $X$; as such, whatever the cardinality of $X$ is, that is also the cardinality of $f(X)$. So indeed, $f(X)$ is countable if and only if $X$ is countable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was hoping that it could be show that $f(X)$ is countable for any $X$, as part of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436294/why-does-a-countable-partition-subset-a-of-x-with-a-an-infinite-sigma). Do you have any thoughts on it?